# Map preserving intervals but discontinuous

Tags: continuity, compactness

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a map sending closed intervals to closed intervals. Prove that $f$ is continuous or find a counter example.

WLOG we just have to prove continuity at $0$ and we can also assume that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$ (by considering $x\mapsto (f(x)-f(0))/(f(1)-f(0))$ ).

I build up this question while thinking of the question [Mappings preserving convex polyhedra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322771/mappings-preserving-convex-polyhedra).

Comment: You tagged it with "compactness" but didn't make any mention in the question, so I feel like some telepathy (or some subliminal messaging) might be going on here. Can you clarify any hypotheses you are thinking of?

Comment: @rschwieb It is useful to note that closed intervals are precisely the compact connected subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @AlexBecker It's useful to know that's what the poster means by closed intervals, too, if that's the case.

Comment: @rschwieb, I had in mind that closed and bounded interval are the compact sets. Sorry for not mentioning it in the post.

Comment: @GillesBonnet Thanks! That makes everything clear.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is false. Consider
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\sin \frac{1}{x} & x\ne 0\\
0 &x = 0
\end{cases}$$
which is discontinuous at $0$. However, for any closed interval $I$ not containing $0$, we have that $f(I)$ is a closed interval since $f$ is continuous on $I$, and for any closed interval $I$ containing $0$ we have $f(I)=[-1,1]$.

Comment: ohh! classic! Wonder how I did not think about it myself!

Comment: @GillesBonnet What I noticed was that your property is very much like the Intermediate Value Property, and this function is famously discontinuous but satisfies IVP.

Comment: @AlexBecker, $\frac{\sin x}{x} \rightarrow 1^-$ when $x\rightarrow 0$ so the image of  $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ (for $\varepsilon$ small enough)its of the form $\{0\}\cup (1-\delta,1)$ tha it isnt a closed interval

Comment: ok, thanks. Meta question: should I edit the title to: "Map preserving intervals but discontinuous." in order to make it more clear.

Comment: @themaker You're right, I made a typo. Should be right now.

Comment: @GillesBonnet Either is fine (although your current title should read "then", not "than")

Comment: @GillesBonnet Please edit the title.  The title very misleading right now.

Answer (score 1):

A closed map* is not necessarily continuous. As mentioned in e.g., Wikipedia's page, the argument function assigning to a point p in $S^1$ its "total argument" (in the range $[0, 2\pi)$), i.e., the arc-length in radians at any x in  $S^1$ , measured from a fixed point p, is both open, closed, but not continuous ; specifically near the fixed point $p$ , where the value goes from being close to $2\pi$ to being $0$.

Comment: This property is stronger than being a closed map however.